# LoadRunner how to capture active window name (it's a pop-up)

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I facing  problem while correlating script in load-runner.

Issue: There is a pop-up window is opening in my application with attribut like "_WindowName=Quote_dyanmicvalue" the dynamic value length also changes(values is integer).

cannot find the value in above requests.

please help me capturing the above value.

Comment: Which loadrunner protocol are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a transport level virtual user then an application layer GUI event should not matter unless it generates a corresponding transport level flow.

The classical example of this would be the file or print dialogs.  These are entirely local events and do note generate transport level requests.  People without training or without the benefit of refined architectural skills often are confused as to why some GUI level events generate a corresponding script event and others do not, this comes down to the communications architecture of the application and whether your client event generates a corresponding server request|response pair.   Not all gui events do generate such conversation.